# Why Inject Controllers and not Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, controller, action

Why does all dependency injection in ASP.NET MVC3 happen at the controller level instead of at the action level. Controller creation is typically overridden in order to inject dependencies when the controller is instantiated. However, the controller is only instantiated as the result of a request for an action. Why not handle the dependency injection at the action level?

Comment: How would you inject a dependency in an action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is a known pattern and the hooks are in place in MVC to inject into a controller, not an action. There is a controller factor, but not an action factory. You create an instance of the controller, not the method, so thats where the injection needs to take place.

Plus theres a known pattern of constructor injection which would be more appropriate here than some other  method (i.e. action method) injection and it also allows any other setup in your constructor that may be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When creating an instance of the controller, why inject the dependencies of all the methods?

Comment: like what for example? Generally controllers have related dependencies between its actions, for instance an IUnitOfWork. ICache, or ISomeService that is all related to your controller actions

Comment: For example: I have an Index() which reads from a readOnly repository tied to a logging database for concurrency, and an HttpPost Index that saves to a write repository (two actions, each with separate dependencies). The injection would still be in the controller, but the dependencies injected would be action relevant only. The action call will be in HttpContext.

Comment: There are hooks to inject an action, see: IActionInvoker interface at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactioninvoker.aspx

Comment: 'normally' you see all actions in a single repository with the available CRUD actions in a single repository. In fact, every time I've seen this. It doesnt mean you can't deviate, but a common pattern here has merit again why you don't normally see this in MVC. With that said, it doesnt mean you wont come across something like this. I hadn't thought of using IActionInvoker here as its not one of the normal injection points you have to build up by yourself (although possible I think)- Im going to try a little experiment with this to see if I can get it working with Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use model binding as an action method injector of sorts. Here's a little introduction to model binders you can read:

http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx

You could instance and pass repositories, or anything you'd like to the action methods in this way, and it'd be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are starring at a GOD controllers with 10 dependecies and a lot of actions and wonder how this could be made better?

Remember! Controllers should be **skinny** and contain **few actions**. I prefer my controllers to only have one action per HTTP method.

Comment: No, although I like the reference to GOD code, as it amuses me. "per HTTP method" - I am assuming you mean HttpPost and HttpGet and/or CRUD. I was just curious if there was a way to avoid injecting multiple dependencies (such as repositories) into a controller when the dependencies are most likely never all needed at the same time. skinny controllers with few actions are good, I try not to break 200-300 lines of code, but don't make your controllers too small or you will be going overboard and usability of the service will suffer.